# Better code for getting one feature's ratio by group?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

Dataset name : sample.

Col1 : ID

Col2 : SEX (factor with 2 levels "m", "f")

Col3 : SIU (factor with 2 levels "Y", "N")

I want to get the ratio of SEX by SIU.
I can get the result with this code :

```
prop.table(table(sample %>% filter(SIU=="N") %>% select(SEX) ))
prop.table(table(sample %>% filter(SIU=="Y") %>% select(SEX) ))
```

but it consists of 2 sentences so it need to be executed 2 times.

Is there a better, simple way to do same thing?

EDIT :

result of above code

```
>            m            f 
> 0.4529346622 0.5470653378 
>     m            f 
> 0.3604651163 0.6395348837
```

It is what I want to get, but I think my code isn't the best.

Comment: perhaps replace `filter(SIU=="N")` with `group_by(SIU)`

Comment: I am not sure how you want the ratio of sex, but maybe aggregate can help: `aggregate(df$SEX, by=list(df$SIU), table)` or `aggregate(df$SEX, by=list(df$SIU), function(x) sum(x == 'm')/length(x))`

Comment: sorry for my unclear question. I want like this : N : 0.45(male) 0.54(female) , Y : 0.36(male) 0.64(female)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,3,4,5,3,4), SEX = c('m','f','m','f','f','f'), SIU= c('y','y','n','n','n','n'))
aggregate(df$SEX, by=list(df$SIU), function(x) table(x)/length(x))
# Group.1  x.f  x.m
# 1   n   0.75 0.25
# 2   y   0.50 0.50
```

Comment: I didn't know about aggregate function. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem, @Ashtray . Just please mark it as answered if it solved your question.